# Routing Error - No route matches [POST] "/coffee/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting an error with routes, along with form_with method and I can't find where is the problem, I'm creating a simple CRUD and get this trouble with the create method.
controller name:coffee controller
table name:products

Error

```
No route matches [POST] "/coffee/new"
```

coffee controller

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end
  def create
    Product.create(product_params)
  end

  private
  def tweet_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :image, :text)
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="contents row">
  <div class="container">
    <%= form_with(model: @products, method: :post, local: true) do |form| %>
      <h3>投稿する</h3>
      <%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
      <%= form.text_field :image, placeholder: "Image Url" %>
      <%= form.text_area :text, placeholder: "text", rows: "10" %>
      <%= form.submit "SEND" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show routes for this controller?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issue in your code:

**1. Fix the typo in the instance variable**

```
<%= form_with(model: @product, method: :post, local: true) do |form| %>
```

**2. Fix the typo in the parameters**

```
  private

  # This is not revelant to your issue
  # but you need to change tweet_params to product_params
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :image, :text)
  end
```